# Crop image for Tensorflow training or not?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm playing with TensorFlow, I use the [image recognition system](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html). I feed and train the app with own images content.

Everything goes fine until I started to have few categories.

***For exemple at the beginning I had only :***

```
-hat
```

And got a good success on results (scores about 0.95)

***Then I added :***

```
-shoes
-canne
```

And results started to get less accurates, I got **hat** scores with 0,94 on people without hat.

I use the arg ***--how_many_training_steps 4000*** as written in the doc for better results.

So I think I did not teach the app the right way:

- Do I have to feed it with cropped images showing the hat without the body or with the entire body and hat ? Same for shoes, canne, etc...
- How many images per categorie do I need at least to have good results ? I saw the flowers example have about 600-800 pictures per flower name, I have actually 150 images per categorie.
- Do I have to use antagonist images ? like a head or body with a hat in a folder hat and a head or body without hat in a folder no-hat ?
- Do I have to use same image in multiple categories like for a guy with a hat and shoes and a canne I copy the image in folders *hat, shoes, canne*

Answer (score 0):

Inception v3 is an image classification system, meaning it gives a probability of each class for the entire picture. You could use the output probabilities to infer what else is in the picture besides the top result, but that's really not what this model is for.

I'd suggest this:

https://research.googleblog.com/2016/09/show-and-tell-image-captioning-open.html

It could return a caption like "Man wearing a hat with a canne"

EDIT: If you are going to use an image classification system each class should have at least 100 images (thats the bare minimum) and the images should each fit into only one class. Instead of anti-categories like 'no-hat' just have one 'other' category if you want the system to deal with images that don't fall into any category.